# Process Builder not Updating Field

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, workflow

I have a process builder that updates an `opportunity` field only if the related `payment` payment method field is cash or cheque. When testing it out and creating a related payment with payment method cash or cheque, it does not update the `opportunity` field. Is there anything I may be missing?

When a payment is created or edited

[image: Wwhen]

If the payment method field on the `payment` object is cash or cheque

[image]

Set the `amount` field on the related opportunity equal to the `donation amount` field (Formula)

[image]

Full process:

[image]

Comment: does the Payment object have a corresponding Opportunity when the PB is triggered?

Comment: Yes it is a master detail to Opportunity and the master-detail field is filled with the opportunity

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify - in your Cash/Check criteria, did you use OR or AND?

Comment: @DavidCheng I am using OR

Answer (score 0):

> Set the amount field on the related opportunity equal to the donation amount field (Formula)

Your screenshot makes it look like you're actually doing the opposite. You're setting the Donation Amount equal to the Opportunity Amount.

Comment: Oops. I worded it the opposite. The formula is my desired output, but it isn't showing when triggering the criteria

Comment: So you're trying to set Donation Amount = Amount?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Edit: Just tested it and set the payment method field on the related payment record to cash, it doesn't update the donation amount field